# Translation from English to Latin: How to translate formlessness?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, english

So I'm experimenting with some character concepts for a story dealing with Platonic Forms.

So far I have Forma Spatii (the Form of Space) and Forma Tempii (the Form of Time) as characters, as well as Forma Formarum (the Form of Forms).

And I've had this idea of a Form of Formlessness, but I'm not sure how to translate it. Note that Formlessness should be in singular genitive.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What word is "Tempii"? As far as I know, the genitive of "tempus" is "temporis"

Comment: It's a variant, I think. Click on "tempus" in the following link. https://glosbe.com/en/la/time

Comment: Thanks. But at the moment I'm more interested in a translation for formlessness.

Comment: Plato's "form" is not "forma", but "idea".

Comment: @fdb, *forma* (*rerum*) is used as the Latin translation of ἰδέα by both Cicero (*Orator* 10: has **rerum formas** appellat ἰδέας ... Plato) and Apuleius (*De Platone et eius dogmate* 1.5: initia rerum esse tria arbitratur Plato: deum et materiam inabsolutam, informem ... **rerumque formas**, quas ἰδέας idem uocat).

Comment: @cnread. Thanks. I had overlooked those important references.

Comment: The Cicero quotation in fact gives us the correct answer to the original question: "formlessness" is materia inabsoluta informis.

Comment: I thought of Genesis 1 - 'the earth was formless and empty' but I see the Vulgate gives 'inanis et vacua', which I don't think helps us.

Comment: Like wise with Jeremiah 4: 23 'I looked at the earth and it was formless and empty' is given as 'vacua erat et nihili.'

Comment: *Forma informis* - just make it an adjective, not a noun.

Answer (score 4):

According to the *Oxford Latin Dictionary*, the third-declension adjective *informis* means:

> **1** Having no definite or regular shape, formless, featureless, or sim. **b** (of an abstract idea, institution, or sim.) not having a material form. **c** bodiless, disembodied.

Although no related noun is attested in Classical Latin, it's simple enough to derive one on the model of, e.g., *brevis* > *brevitas*. So, if you're open to using a neologism, the noun *informitas* (genitive singular *informitatis*) would be one possibility.

Also, note that *Forma Tempii* doesn't mean 'the Form of Time'; the phrase should be *Forma Temporis*, because *tempus* is a third-declension noun.

---

**Update:** As sumelic has noted, *informitas* actually *is* attested, though in Late Latin, and means 'unshapeliness, ugliness, deformity' (according to Lewis & Short, which I should have checked in addition to *OLD* to begin with). So, yes, my suggestion of *Forma Informitatis* might be misleading.

For alternatives, perhaps one can glean something from, e.g., book 1, lines 5–9 of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*, since that passage describes pre-creation formlessness:

> ante mare et terras et quod tegit omnia caelum
>   unus erat toto naturae vultus in orbe,
>   quem dixere chaos: rudis indigestaque moles
>   nec quicquam nisi pondus iners congestaque eodem
>   non bene iunctarum discordia semina rerum.

Line 6–7 say that nature had one appearance in the whole world, and that this was called 'chaos.' L&S gives as definition II of *chaos* 'The confused, formless, primitive mass out of which the universe was made,' and *OLD* gives 'The formless state of primordial matter or the period of this state.' So maybe *Forma Chai* would work. The problem there is that it could be taken as chaos in the modern sense of the word. Maybe something can be done with the phrase *rudis indigestaque moles* instead.

Or, there's bound to be something in Lucretius.

**Update 2:** I note that Apuleius (*De Platone et eius dogmate* 1.5) uses the adjective *informis* specifically in the context of Plato's forms:

> initia rerum esse tria arbitratur Plato: deum et materiam inabsolutam, informem, nulla specie nec qualitatis significatione distinctam, **rerumque formas**, quas ἰδέας idem uocat.

So, if one goes by classical meanings, I still think there's some justification for the noun *informitas*.

Comment: "[informitas](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/23683/informitas-informitatis)" does seem to be attested (or at least listed in some dictionaries), but it apparently has been used at times to mean "unshapeliness", i.e. "having an unpleasing physical form" rather than "lacking any physical form". It seems it *can* have the latter meaning, but it might be ambiguous

Comment: @sumelic. Thanks for alerting me to the late existence/usage of the noun informitas. Given the proliferation of such abstract nouns in late Latin, I should have known to check Lewis & Short and/or a medieval lexicon in addition to OLD. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Since *chaos* comes from Greek you could also use the Greek form of the genitive. Sounds a bit unnatural to me but I know straight-up Greek declension is attested in Latin.

Comment: I think the idea is similar to how "lack of beauty" in English means "ugly." While *forma* can mean "shape," *formosus* indicates physical beauty.